# How can I control 2 lights, that are controlled by 1 switch, independently without having to re-route wires?

Tags: electrical

My contractor installed 2 beside lights dropping from the ceiling but only provided 1 switch to turn both ON/OFF simultaneously.  Obviously that's a poor design because one person may want to go to sleep and turn OFF their light, while the other may want it ON to read, etc.

Are there any wireless solutions out there that can fix this issue without having to rewire the lights and wire new switches in the wall?

Comment: You must reroute wires to put the two lamps on separate wall switches. Are the lights low enough to reach while lying or sitting in bed? You could change one fixture (or both fixtures) to a type that could be turned off by hand or by remote control. The wall switch would have to be on for either to be on, but either could be turned off independently.

Answer (score 1):

There are [remote controlled switches that fit a light socket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075D8H4MG), and [LED lamps that have remote controls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06Y27W7NZ). These are just two examples; you may need a different base to fit the fixture.

Comment: The doctor takes the prize.  The right answer here in the late 2010s is smart switches.